# KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME' in pyspark on Jupyter on Google-Cloud-DataProc

Tags: pyspark, jupyter, google-cloud-dataproc

When trying to show a SparkDF (Test), I get a KeyError, as shown below. Probably something goes wrong in the function I used before `Test.show(3)`.

The KeyError says: KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'. 
I assume SPARK_HOME is not defined on the master and/or workers. Is there a way I can specify the SPARK_HOME directory automatically on both? Preferably by using a initialization action.

Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
    ----> 1 Test.show(3)

```
/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate)
    255         +---+-----+
    256         """
--> 257         print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
    258 
    259     def __repr__(self):
```

...

```
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put the following in an initialization action:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << EOF | tee -a /etc/profile.d/custom_env.sh /etc/*bashrc >/dev/null
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark/
EOF
```

You'll want to put that init action before your jupyter installation action to make sure that it's present when the jupyter process starts up.

Edit: To specify the two init actions, you can list them in a comma-separated list without spaces, like this:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create \
    --initialization-actions gs://mybucket/spark_home.sh,gs://mybucket/jupyter.sh ...
```

Comment: Adding the initialization action did not resolve the problem. I tried to put the code above in the jupyter init action (without hashbang) and also as separate init action before the jupyter init action.

Comment: As you suggested, I created a bash script (spark_home.sh) containing the content as specified above. Even when including this as initialization action, I get the spark home error. `gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster --zone=europe-west1-d  --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 --master-boot-disk-size 100 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 --worker-boot-disk-size 50 --project myproject --bucket mybucket --initialization-actions gs://stijnbucket/sh/spark_home.sh --initialization-actions gs://stijnbucket/sh/jupyter.sh`

Comment: After using that initialization action, if you SSH into the master node and type `echo ${SPARK_HOME}` does it show as being correctly set at least for the logged in case?

Comment: `echo ${SPARK_HOME}` is not showing anything on the master nor on the workers. SPARK_HOME is not defined (for my user). For root I cannott check.

Comment: You should be able to become root on any of the machines by running `sudo su`.

Comment: Ah, so, it's possible the flag "--initialization-actions' isn't appending to the list on the second argument and is instead replacing the argument. Try: `--initialization-actions gs://stijnbucket/sh/spark_home.sh, gs://stijnbucket/sh/jupyter.sh` instead of repeating the "--initialization-actions" flag

Comment: If I `sudo su`, SPARK_HOME is empty (for master and worker). Nevertheless if I run `os.environ`, SPARK_HOME is defined as '/usr/lib/spark'. Even if I `sudo s` on master node SSH and afterwards `export SPARK_HOME=`usr/lib/spark`it get defined, but if I close and reopen master SSH, SPARK_HOME is empty again.

Comment: Giving two initializaton-actions arguments seperated by a comma does not work. The cluster creation command fails.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left a space after my comma; did you try doing it without any space after the comma when passing the comma-separated list of init actions?

Comment: Comma-separated init actions without space works! Thanks for the advice and the patience!

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for verifying it works! Updated the answer to add the example of passing the comma-separated list.

Comment: works great for installing livy as well since I got the same error installing livy on dataproc