# Could not find valid SPARK_HOME on dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, rdd, google-cloud-dataproc

Spark job executed by Dataproc cluster on Google Cloud gets stuck on a task `PythonRDD.scala:446`

The error log says `Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching` ... paths under `/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/`

The thing is, SPARK_HOME should be set by default on a dataproc cluster.
Other spark jobs that don't use RDDs work just fine.

During the initialization of the cluster I do not reinstall spark (but I have tried to, which I previously thought caused the issue).

I also found out that all my executors were removed after a minute of running the task.

And yes, I have tried to run the following initialization action and it didn't help:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << EOF | tee -a /etc/profile.d/custom_env.sh /etc/*bashrc >/dev/null
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark/
EOF
```

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PATH issue: Could not find valid SPARK\_HOME while searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991888/path-issue-could-not-find-valid-spark-home-while-searching)

Comment: @stefanobaghino it's not a duplicate. In that issue he's running spark locally. Dataproc cluster has spark pre-installed.

Comment: you should add SPARK_HOME environmental variable with value
 "{path_to_spark}/bin"

Comment: @Lejla You have no control over `PATH`?

Comment: this is not a dupe @stefanobaghino DataProc is a managed service, it should have installed frameworks properly.

Comment: @Lejla did you contact your provider ?

Comment: @eliasah Not really sure how, I was hoping someone responsible from Google would find it here. But I think the issue has something to do with YARN .

Comment: @Lejla take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652940/keyerror-spark-home-in-pyspark-on-jupyter-on-google-cloud-dataproc), if this solves your issue, I'll close the question as a dupe

Comment: @DennisHuo can it be the case here ?

Comment: @eliasah I've tried that. Didn't help. I've got the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyError: 'SPARK\_HOME' in pyspark on Jupyter on Google-Cloud-DataProc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652940/keyerror-spark-home-in-pyspark-on-jupyter-on-google-cloud-dataproc)

Comment: Can you clarify how you're invoking spark? Are there init actions running on your cluster? If your remove init actions, does your cluster exhibit the same issue? What spark settings are you providing when launching your cluster / job?

Comment: @AngusDavis in my init actions I set up python3 to be used as PYSPARK_PYTHON, set up PYTHONHASHSEED and install pip and some python libraries (not spark nor pyspark). I can't really remove it, since none of my code would work.

Comment: @AngusDavis oh and I invoke spark like this `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` and I have also tried creating new spark context, but it was the same.  I don't use any specific spark settings when creating the cluster or submitting the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a custom mapping function. When I put the function to a separate file the problem disappeared.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on your solution? I.e. do you have a github link, perhaps? Or could you please describe in more details? I think I face the same issue, and your solution may help.