# google dataproc: which spark directory to use for setting $SPARK_HOME env var?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

On google DataProc, `$whereis spark` returned two directories. `$SPARK_HOME env` wasn't set by default. Which one of the two directories should I set `$SPARK_HOME` to?

```
svermoli@cluster-bigdl-0p4-deploy-m:~/BigDL$ whereis spark
spark: /usr/lib/spark /etc/spark
svermoli@cluster-bigdl-0p4-deploy-m:~/BigDL$ ls /usr/lib/spark

bin   data      external  LICENSE   NOTICE  R          RELEASE  work
conf  examples  jars      licenses  python  README.md  sbin     yarn
svermoli@cluster-bigdl-0p4-deploy-m:~/BigDL$ ls /etc/spark

conf  conf.dist

svermoli@cluster-bigdl-0p4-deploy-m:~/BigDL$ echo $SPARK_HOME

svermoli@cluster-bigdl-0p4-deploy-m:~/BigDL$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `/usr/lib/spark/` as is where the runtime is located, `etc/spark` is for configuration files. Also, you can set it as an initialization action if you need to do it everytime you create a cluster as explained in Dennis Huo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652940/keyerror-spark-home-in-pyspark-on-jupyter-on-google-cloud-dataproc).